# Check if 2 variables contain exactly the same text and do action using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below and i want to check if the two variables "n" and "w" contain exactly the same text and do an action. However i can store in the variables the text string but when i try to set the conditional it doesn't work?

What am i doing wrong ?

```js
 var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[3] = "Thirsday";
    weekday[4] = "Πέμπτη";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var w =  $('.today-tag').text();
   
  
    if(n === w) {
    $('.today-tag').text('TODAY');
    } else {
    $('.today-tag').text('');
    }
```

```css
.today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-day">Sunday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Monday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Tuesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Wednesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Thirsday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Friday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Saturday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many `div` with class `today-tag`,so `$('.today-tag').text()` will not return the value you want.you can use `each()` to compare the value

```js
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[3] = "Thirsday";
    weekday[4] = "Πέμπτη";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    $(".today-tag").each(function(index,element){
     if($.trim($(element).parent().text())== n){
        $(element).text("Today");
      }else{
        $(element).empty();
      }
    });
```

```css
.today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-day">Sunday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Monday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Tuesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Wednesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Thirsday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Friday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Saturday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in `$('.today-tag').text()`. You have to use the index of the current date in the array and `parent()` to get the text:

```js
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);

weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
weekday[3] = "Thirsday";
weekday[4] = "Πέμπτη";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
var idx = d.getDay();
var w =  $('.today-tag:eq('+idx+')').parent().text();

if(n === w) {
  $('.today-tag:eq('+idx+')').text('TODAY');
} else {
  $('.today-tag').text('');
}
```

```css
.today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-day">Sunday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Monday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Tuesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Wednesday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Thirsday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Friday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
<div class="the-day">Saturday<div class="today-tag"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the **.today-tag** is an empty div element so we have to compare it with **.the-day** instead
apart from that the **$('.the-day')**  will return an array of elements thus we need to use
the **date()** object there as well.. and lastly we just want today next to the current day so we use **children()** to return array of children of the selected day.. since you only have one child object we use 0th elemement.

i hope that explain's it well. 
(ps: i am no jquery expert been using vanilla js for long time thus there might be better alternative to children() method )

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);

    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[3] = "Thirsday";
    weekday[4] = "Πέμπτη";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var w =  $('.the-day')[d.getDay()];
    var today = $(w).children()[0]; //selects first child

    if(n === $(w).text()) {
    $(today).text('TODAY');

    } else {
    $(today).text('');
    }
});
```